# Lindbladian and Dynamical semigroups

Tags: quantum-mechanics, density-operator, open-quantum-systems

I am attempting to learn a bit more about open quantum systems.

Often we derive master equations or Heisenberg-Langevin equations where we have something like

\begin{align}
\dot{\rho}(t) = \mathcal{L}[\rho(t)]\\
\dot{A}(t) = \mathcal{L}^{\dagger}[A(t)]
\end{align}

Here $\rho$ is the density matrix of the system and $A$ is an arbitrary system operator and $\mathcal{L}$ Lindbladian superoperator given by

$$
\mathcal{L}[\mathcal{O}] = -\frac{i}{\hbar}[H,\mathcal{O}] + \sum_i \gamma_i\left(L_i\mathcal{O}L_i^{\dagger} - \frac{1}{2}\left\{L_i^{\dagger}L_i,\mathcal{O}\right\}\right)
$$

for any operator $\mathcal{O}$.
See for example [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/280398/lindblad-equation-for-heisenberg-operators?rq=1).

It is said that the Lindblad form gives the most general form to generate Markovian dynamics.

Clearly there must be more general master equations which are non-Markovian. It seems to me that one could derive the most general form in the following way. Suppose we have a system which comes from a tensor product of two systems, $A$ and $B$.
We have

\begin{align}
\rho(t) &= U(t)\rho(0) U^{\dagger}(t) = e^{\mathcal{L}t}[\rho(0)]\\
\dot{\rho}(t) &= \left[\dot{U}(t)U^{\dagger}(t),\rho(t) \right] = -\frac{i}{\hbar}[H(t),\rho(t)] = \mathcal{L}[\rho(t)]
\end{align}

where $U$ represents the time evolution operator. We then take the partial trace to get

\begin{align}
\rho_A(t) &= \text{Tr}_B[\rho(t)]=\text{Tr}_B\left[e^{\mathcal{L}t}\rho(0)\right]\\
\dot{\rho}_A(t) &= \frac{d}{dt}\text{Tr}_B\left[\rho(t)\right] = \text{Tr}_B\left[\dot{\rho}(t) \right] = \text{Tr}_B[\mathcal{L}[\rho(t)]] = \mathcal{L}_A[\rho_A(t)]
\end{align}

Here $\mathcal{L}$ generates unitary dynamics for $\rho$, while tracing out the dynamics of system $B$ leads to $\mathcal{L}_A$ to generate the not-necessarily unitary dynamics for $\rho_A$.

My questions are as follows.

1) Is what I have described actually the way to derive the most general form for a quantum master equation?

2) I guess the derivation above will not lead to the Lindblad form because it does not necessarily generate Markovian dynamics? Is this correct?

3) Is it the restriction that $e^{\mathcal{L}_A t}$ is an element of a dynamical semi-group the mathematical fact which leads to $\mathcal{L}_A$ having the Lindblad form? Is the dynamical semigroup restriction the same as requiring Markovian dynamics?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have done more reading and see an important point I missed above. In my last line for $\dot{\rho_A(t)}$ I made the step

$$
\text{Tr}_B(\mathcal{L}[\rho(t)]) = \mathcal{L}_A[\rho_A(t)]
$$

This step is not justified in general. Namely, the problem is as follows. I think it is true that $\text{Tr}_B(\mathcal{L}[\rho(t)])$ can be written as a function of $\rho_A$, however, the dependence may not only include $\rho_A(t)$. In particular it may depend on $\rho_A$ at time $t$ as well as other earlier times. Physically this corresponds to the idea that information about system $A$ could leak into system $B$, then, if system $B$ has memory this information can feed back into system $A$ meaning that the current time evolution of system $A$ will depend, in general, on the prior state of system $A$ and all earlier times.

In physics we like differential equations for objects. We like it when the time evolution for an object at time $t$ is related to a function of that object also at time $t$. We can see that the above paragraph messes with this desiderata. This is why we impose the Markovity of system $B$ which ensures the master equation can be written in the form above.

I still await an answer from someone more expert than me but here are my answers to my own questions.

1) What I described was not quite the most general form because I made the above unjustified assumption.
I still think that

\begin{align}
\dot{\rho}_A(t) = \text{Tr}_B[\mathcal{L}[\rho(t)]]
\end{align}

Is the most general form we can write down where $\mathcal{L}$ generates unitary dynamics for $\rho(t)$. Unfortunately I don't really know how to write the RHS of this equation as a function of $\rho_A$ as I would like to. Even given an explicit form for $\rho(t)$ and $\mathcal{L}$ I wouldn't know how to do it I think..

2) It is correct that this general form does not necessarily lead to a Lindblad form.

3) I am pretty certain the time evolution operator being part of a semi-group is the same as the Markov requirement.

To summarize and get to the heart of the question: if we even write down

$$
\dot{\rho}_A(t) = \mathcal{L}_A[\rho_A(t)]
$$

We have ALREADY assumed Markov evolution. This means that $\mathcal{L}$ must be of the Lindblad form [1]. If we want something more general we must abandon the idea of $\dot{\rho}_A(t)$ depending only on $\rho_A(t)$ and not $\rho_A(t')$ for other times $t'$. This is not something I personally would like to abandon so I'll stick to Markov evolution and Lindblad forms for the time being!

[1] G. Lindblad, On the generators of quantum dynamical semigroups,
Commun. Math. Phys 48, 119, (1976).