# How to show that the Liouvillian fulfills $\langle A, \mathcal{L}B\rangle = \langle \mathcal{L}^\dagger A,B\rangle $?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, open-quantum-systems

How can I show that the Liouvillian superoperator $\mathcal{L}$ satisfies
$$
\langle A,\mathcal{L}B\rangle=\langle \mathcal{L}^\dagger A,B\rangle 
$$
where $\langle A,B\rangle =\mathrm{Tr}(A^\dagger B)$ is the Hilber-Schmidt product, and $A$ and $B$ are two operators.
In other words, how can I prove that
$$
\mathrm{Tr}(A^\dagger \mathcal{L} B)=\mathrm{Tr}((\mathcal{L}^\dagger A^\dagger)B) 
$$

Comment: sry, the one in the body

Comment: Isn’t this how the [Hermitian adjoint](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_adjoint) of an operator is *defined*?

Comment: What Ghoster said + see https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/280398/lindblad-equation-for-heisenberg-operators